# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validationFailed' of undefined

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Iam trying to use tab key on cell Editor in dataTable of Primefaces 6.2. On click of tab key for last row in my dataTable i get the following error message in my console

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'validationFailed' of undefined
```

Below is my code

```
  <p:dataTable id="dtSalsLst" 
                         value="#{userEnrollmentService.salesmenMstList}" 
                         selection="#{userEnrollmentService.selectdSalmenMstList}"
                         filteredValue="#{userEnrollmentService.filteredSalmenMstList}"                          
                         scrollable="true"
                         var="salsTm" widgetVar="SlsTm"                        
                         emptyMessage="No #{custom.labels.get('IDS_SALES_TEAM')} found."  
                         paginator="true"     
                         rowSelectMode="add"
                         paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" 
                         class="tblmain"
                         rows="10" rowKey="#{salsTm.smanId}" 
                         editable="true" editMode="cell"                          
                         tableStyle="table-layout:auto" resizableColumns="true"
                         >
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" />
                <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"  />
                <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox"  />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" />
                <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"  />

            <p:column  selectionMode="multiple" style="width:50px;text-align: center"/>

            <p:column id="colSlstm" headerText="#{custom.labels.get('IDS_SALES_TEAM')}" filterBy="#{salsTm.smanName}" sortBy="#{salsTm.smanName}" filterMatchMode="contains"  >
                <p:outputLabel  id="otptLblSmanName" value="#{salsTm.smanName}"  />
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="colCompSplit" headerText="Company split">
                #{salsTm.smanCompanySplit}
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="colRepPct" headerText="Rep %" >
                <p:cellEditor >
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText  value="#{salsTm.repPct}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <!--Feature #6659: User Onboard: Setup Sales Team   21/01/22 by harshithad-->
                        <p:inputNumber id="inptTxtRepPct" value="#{salsTm.repPct}" maxlength="5"  decimalPlaces="2" maxValue="100">
                            <p:ajax process="@this" event="change" 
                                    update="frmSlsList:dtSalsLst" />
                            <!--<f:convertNumber type="number"  maxFractionDigits="2" groupingUsed="true" maxIntegerDigits="15" />-->
                        </p:inputNumber>
                    </f:facet>

                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
```

I also get this java Exception in terminal where i build the application.

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "undefined"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.CellEditFeature.encode(CellEditFeature.java:38)
        at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:87)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
        at javax.faces.
```

Below I have attached the images of error message in my console.

[image: Error Message]